# vba how to match cell with range and return value in adjacent cells?

Tags: excel, vba

Excuse my lack of coding language, I'm just getting into vba coding.
I have a list of Manufacturers (names) with contact details on one that I like to be populated on my "SPECSHEET" automatically when choosing manufacturer.

Worksheet "SPECSHEET" is fully created from macro.

Worksheet "CONTACTS" has a list of names in column A and phone numbers in column C

Worksheet "DATASHEET" holds information about each luminaire.

I am successful in showing the right manufacturer name:

```
Worksheets("SPECSHEET").Cells(Company, 5).Value = Worksheets("DATASHEET").Cells(1, 5).Value
```

But I like the row below to show the phone number:

```
If Worksheets("SPECSHEET").Cells(3, 4).Value = Worksheets("CONTACT").Range(A:A).Value Then
Worksheets("SPECSHEET").Cells(3, 5).Value = Worksheets("CONTACT").Cells(B "name adjacent to the matched name in column A) 
End If
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim t
t = Application.Match(Worksheets("SPECSHEET").Cells(3, 4).Value, Worksheets("CONTACT").Range("A:A"), 0)
If Not IsError(t) Then
    Worksheets("SPECSHEET").Cells(3, 5).Value = Worksheets("CONTACT").Range("B" & t)
Else
    Worksheets("SPECSHEET").Cells(3, 5).Value = "Not Found"
End If
```

It uses the worksheet function MATCH() to find the row and then returns the value in Column B of that row.  If it is not found then it returns `Not Found`.

Comment: Thanks Scott, perfect!

Comment: @Ida please mark as correct by clicking the grey/green check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.

Comment: Right. I tried to click the arrows :P Hint taken, will look at intro to this page now ;) Thanks